# Traefik not generating TLS certificate (Error 401)

Tags: docker, cloudflare, traefik

I'm hoping someone here can help me.

I've set up my Traefik in docker on a Synology NAS, with ports 80 and 443 pointed to it. Everything works except for TLS. I'm using Cloudflare DNS challenge, and no matter what I put in it always generates a 401 invalid credentials error. I've triple checked my email and API key are correct. Anyone else experiencing this issue? I'd really appreciate any help on this :)

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
traefik:
    image: traefik:latest
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - "CF_API_EMAIL=email"
      - "CF_API_KEY=api"
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/traefik/data/traefik.yaml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/traefik/data/config.yaml:/config.yml:ro
      - ${USERDIR}/traefik/data/acme:/acme

whoami:
    container_name: whoami
    image: containous/whoami
    networks:
      - proxy
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`example.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.tls.certResolver=myresolver"
```

**traefik.yaml**

```
entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
    network: proxy
  file:
    filename: ./config.yml

certificatesResolvers:
  myresolver:
    acme:
      email: email
      storage: /acme/acme.json
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: cloudflare
        resolvers:
          - 1.1.1.1:53
          - 1.0.0.1:53
      caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
```

**log**

```
level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains "example.com": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[example.com] [example.com] acme: error presenting token: cloudflare: failed to create TXT record: error from makeRequest: HTTP status 401: invalid credentials\n" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=whoami@docker rule="Host(`example.com`)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered in the github post - https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/6782

It is due to cloudflare recently removing the support for .tk .ml and few other TLDs to use their apis